# SwuftUI performance very bad with many Rectangles to be colored

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I created a LazyVGrid of rectangles like pixels. I'd like to color a part or all of that with a delay in order to perform a simil animation during the filling, but the performance is very bad, I think it's refreshing all the rectangles every update.

the behavior
[image]

the code

```
struct Pixel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var isColored: Bool
}


class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var pixels: [Pixel]
    
    init(totalPixels: Int) {
        pixels = (1...totalPixels).map{ Pixel(id: $0, isColored: false)}
    }
    
    func pixelsRange(num:Int, clusterDimension:Int) -> [Pixel]{
        return Array(pixels[(num-1)*clusterDimension..<clusterDimension*num])
    }

    func startFillingAllAnimated() {
        for idx in pixels.indices {
            let addTime = idx
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(addTime) * 0.1) {
                self.pixels[idx].isColored = true
            }
        }
    }
}
struct TotalView: View {
    
    static var totalPixels = 1280
    
    @StateObject var model = Model(totalPixels: totalPixels)
    
    var clusterDimension = 16
    
    static let bigSpacing:CGFloat = 2
    
    let bigColumns = [
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: bigSpacing),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: bigSpacing),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: bigSpacing),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: bigSpacing),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: bigSpacing),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: bigSpacing),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: bigSpacing),
        
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: bigSpacing)
    ]
    
    @State var numToBeColored: Int = 8
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {

            Button("start") {
                model.startFillingAllAnimated()
            }
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: bigColumns, alignment: .center, spacing: 2){
                    ForEach(0..<TotalView.totalPixels/clusterDimension, id: \.self) { num in
                        ClusterView(pixels: $model.pixels, clusterNumber: num, clusterDimension: clusterDimension, color: .red)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 4)
        }
        
    }
}





struct ClusterView: View {
    
    
    @Binding var pixels: [Pixel]
    let clusterNumber: Int
    let clusterDimension: Int
    let color: Color
    
    static let spacing:CGFloat = 2
    static let boxDimension:CGFloat = 9

    let columns = [
        GridItem(.fixed(boxDimension), spacing: spacing),
        GridItem(.fixed(boxDimension), spacing: spacing),
        GridItem(.fixed(boxDimension), spacing: spacing),
        GridItem(.fixed(boxDimension), spacing: spacing)
    ]

    var body: some View {
  
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: ClusterView.spacing) {
            ForEach(pixels[clusterNumber*clusterDimension..<clusterDimension*(clusterNumber+1)], id: \.self) { pixel in
                Rectangle()
                    .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                    .border(color)
                    .foregroundColor(pixel.isColored ? color:.clear)
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct TotalView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TotalView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that this code:

```
func startFillingAllAnimated() {
    
    for idx in pixels.indices {
        let addTime = idx
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(addTime) * 0.1) {
            self.pixels[idx].isColored = true
        }
    }
}
```

runs in a very tight loop, and executes **completely** almost instantaneously.

You can confirm that by adding a `print()` statement at the end:

```
func startFillingAllAnimated() {
    
    for idx in pixels.indices {
        let addTime = idx
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(addTime) * 0.1) {
            self.pixels[idx].isColored = true
        }
    }

    print("returning")
}
```

You will see "returning" printed in the debug console before the first grid square changes to filled.

So, all those calls to `.asycAfter` have gotten queued up and the UI update gets "clogged up."

You may want to try this approach...

We'll create a Timer, filling in the next grid square in the array each time the Timer repeats. This way we're only setting `.isColored` on one square at a time, and, as an added benefit, it gives us a way to **stop** the process before the "grid fill" has completed (such as adding a "Stop" button to go along with the "Start" button:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var pixels: [Pixel]
    
    @Published var myTimer: Timer? = nil

    init(totalPixels: Int) {
        pixels = (1...totalPixels).map{ Pixel(id: $0, isColored: false)}
    }
    
    func pixelsRange(num:Int, clusterDimension:Int) -> [Pixel]{
        return Array(pixels[(num-1)*clusterDimension..<clusterDimension*num])
    }
    
    func startFillingAllAnimated() {
        // local index var
        var idx: Int = 0
        // create and start a Timer
        myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { timer in
            // if we've reached the end of the array, Stop the Timer
            if idx == self.pixels.count {
                timer.invalidate()
                return
            }
            self.pixels[idx].isColored = true
            idx += 1
        }
    }

    // call this if we want to Stop the Timer
    //  before the grid has been completely filled
    func stopFilling() {
        if let t = myTimer {
            t.invalidate()
        }
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit**

If using a Timer in that way is too slow, you could try this approach.

Using a background thread for the loop, with a (very small) `.sleep` delay, can make it much quicker.

Here's another version of your `Model` class. I included "start / stop / resume" buttons so the fill can be interrupted and then either re-started from the beginning or resumed from where it was when the stop button was tapped:

```
    Button("start") {
        model.startFillingAllAnimated()
    }
    Button("stop") {
        model.stopFilling()
    }
    Button("resume") {
        model.resumeFilling()
    }
```

and the `Model` class becomes:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var pixels: [Pixel]
    
    // so we can interrupt the filling loop
    @Published var keepRunning: Bool = false
    
    init(totalPixels: Int) {
        pixels = (1...totalPixels).map{ Pixel(id: $0, isColored: false)}
    }
    
    func pixelsRange(num:Int, clusterDimension:Int) -> [Pixel]{
        return Array(pixels[(num-1)*clusterDimension..<clusterDimension*num])
    }
    
    func startFillingAllAnimated() {
        // if "start" button tapped,
        //  "un-color" all the pixels
        for idx in self.pixels.indices {
            self.pixels[idx].isColored = false
        }
        // start filling them
        resumeFilling()
    }
    
    func resumeFilling() {
        // if ALL pixels are already "colored" don't do anything (just return)
        guard let i = pixels.firstIndex(where: {$0.isColored == false}) else { return }
        // set the running flag
        keepRunning = true
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            // start at the first non-colored pixel
            for idx in i..<self.pixels.count {
                // insert a slight delay
                //  based on quick testing...
                //  0.0020 will take about 3 seconds to fill them all
                //  0.0010 will take about 1.5 seconds to fill them all
                //  0.0002 will take about 0.3 seconds to fill them all
                //  anything shorter pretty much fills them all instantly
                //  so, you probably want somewhere between
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.0010)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.pixels[idx].isColored = true
                }
                // if keepRunning was set to false, break out of the loop
                if !self.keepRunning {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // call this if we want to Stop
    //  before the grid has been completely filled
    func stopFilling() {
        self.keepRunning = false
    }
    
}
```

Comment: it's working, but also if I reduce the time interval, it takes a lot of time to fill all, any idea to do it quikly?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia - see the **Edit** in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try to change your method with this one:

```
func startFillingAllAnimated() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        for idx in self.pixels.indices {
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.03)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.pixels[idx].isColored = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```